# Index rebuild fails in sitecore 7

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have been working on the ContentSearchAPI in sitecore.Here is my configuration for Lucene Search configuration.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="movieshop_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
            <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/movieShopSearchConfiguration" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster" />
            </strategies>
            <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              </policies>
            </commitPolicyExecutor>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/movieshop</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <movieShopSearchConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
          <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>
          <analyzer ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/analyzer" />
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="_uniqueid"            storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED"    vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
            </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
            <field fieldName="releasedecade">MovieShop.BusinessLayer.Search.ComputedFields.DecadeComputedField,MovieShop.BusinessLayer</field>
          </fields>
          <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
            <Movie>{7D2F4318-029A-461B-854E-FD7CFB4C4F6A}</Movie>
          </include>
          <fieldReaders ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/fieldReaders"/>
          <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/indexFieldStorageValueFormatter"/>
          <indexDocumentPropertyMapper ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/indexDocumentPropertyMapper"/>
        </movieShopSearchConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The above configuration works fine in sitecore version 7.2 but when i try to use the same configuration in Sitecore 7 it fails.I'm getting the following error.

> Could not create instance of type:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex. No matching
>   constructor was found

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider

should be

Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch

Comment: is there anything need to change in analyzers?